# Getting values of my_dict and assign them to a variable called my_values

Tags: dictionary, variables, key-value-store

Please can someone help out. I tried to assign values I got from my_dict to store in a new variable my_values and it is giving me error. See below what I tried to do:

my_dict = {"key_1": 1, "key_2": 2}

my_values = my_dict.values{"key_1": 1, "key_2": 2}

values_view = my_values.values

print(my_values)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax